# Is The Spatial Node added automatically to the Spatial Layer

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I am new to neo4j.

I have  a csv in which two spatial informations are present : *pickup* and *dropoff*.

i created a trip relationship between *pickup node* and *dropoff node*, then i added the pickup node to a geohash Spatial Layer.

*My questions is*:

is the dropoff node added as well to the spatial layer by adding the pickup node ?

do i need to add the dropoff node to the spatial layer as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the **two nodes** to the spatial layer.